# RelaxNG - *any* attribute?

Tags: validation, relaxng

Is there a way to define an *any* name attribute?  I'm validating code where users can and do apply their own attributes for  tags and the like, which don't impact my project.

```
<define name="div">
  <zeroOrMore>
    <attribute name="*">
      <text />
    </attribute>
  </zeroOrMore>
  <text />
</define>
```

Answer (score 4):

[`<anyName/>`](http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html#IDAFLZR) seems to be what you are looking for:

```
<define name="div">
  <zeroOrMore>
    <attribute>
     <anyName/>
    </attribute>
  </zeroOrMore>
  <text/>
</define>
```